# search form using laravel shows 'Call to a member function getNumCommentsStr() on a non-object'

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-4

i have made a search bar using laravel, but it did not succeed. it shows the error as said below. And it seems that something wrong with my post object. But i do not know where.

source code as follows, thanks for helping.

//the searchController for seach code

```
       public function search(){

        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

        if(empty($keyword)){
            return Redirect::route('/');
            //->with('message',array('type' => 'alert', 'content' => '不能为空'))
        }

        $posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        $tags = Tag::where('count','>','0')->orderBy('count','desc')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();

        return Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts->toArray())->with('tags',$tags);
   }

   public function searchResults(){

     return View::make('frontend.search.search',['posts' =>     Session::get('posts'),'tags' => Session::get('tags')]);
   }
```

//search bar route

```
      Route::get('/searchResults', array(

    'uses' => 'SearchController@searchResults',
    'as' => 'searchResults'  
  )); 

  Route::post('/search', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'uses' => 'SearchController@search',
    'as' => 'search'  
  ));
```

//search from

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/search','method' => 'post','class'=>''))}}
            {{ Form::token()}}
            <label for="docSearch">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </label>

            <div class="searchInput">
                {{Form::text('keyword', '', array('class'=>'docsSearch', 'placeholder'=>'搜索论坛动态...'))}}
          {{ Form::submit('提交',array('class'=>''))}} 
{{Form::close()}}
```

//now i just wanna to get it like this:

```
    @if(!$posts)
{{'<section class="oneQuestion">sorry,no content...</section>'}}
@else

  @foreach($posts as $post)
      <section class="oneQuestion">
          <div class="askResult">

<!--             <i class="fa fa-question notSolved"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check solved" style="display:none;"></i> -->

          @if($post->getNumCommentsStr() == 0)
            <a href="{{URL::route('viewPost', array('id' => $post->id))}}#reviews" class="notSolved"><span class="post_comment_Num">{{$post->getNumCommentsStr()}}</span>
             <span> 回答</span>
            </a> 
          @else 
            <a href="{{URL::route('viewPost', array('id' => $post->id))}}#reviews" class="solved"><span class="post_comment_Num">{{$post->getNumCommentsStr()}}</span>
             <span> 回答</span>
            </a> 
          @endif   

          </div><!-- 
       --><div class="titlePart">
            <span>
                {{$post->user->username}}  
                {{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}          
            </span>
              <a href="{{ URL::route('viewPost', $post->id)}}">
              {{--  {{ substr($post->content,0,200) }}... --}}
              {{$post->title}}
              </a>
               <div class="tagWrapper">
                @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
                         <span class="askTag" title="">{{$tag->name}} </span>            
                @endforeach                 
               </div>
          </div>
      </section>      
  @endforeach
@endif
<div class="forumLink">
   {{$posts->links()}}
</div>
```

//it showed me an error:

```
**Call to a member function getNumCommentsStr() on a non-object**
```

and my getNumCommentsStr like:

```
       public function getNumCommentsStr()
   {
    $num = $this->reviews()->count();

    //  if($num == 1){
    //  return "1";
    //  }

    return $num;
   }
```

code seems a lot but i wanna to make it clear so you can find any errors. Thanks again.

**Edit 2**
Thanks for NightMICU's suggest and I change

```
Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts->toArray())->with('tags',$tags);
```

to the following:

Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts')->with('tags',$tags);

THE result is without any alert any more, it just shows: sorry, no content...
And did not show any search result, any problem? Thanks

**EDIT TWO**

//delete the searchResult method, all in one search method so that i can return the view in right in the search method.

```
       public function search(){
            $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
            if(empty($keyword)){
                return Redirect::route('developer');
                //->with('message',array('type' => 'alert', 'content' => '不能为空'))
            }
            $posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
            $tags = Tag::where('count','>','0')->orderBy('count','desc')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();

            return View::make('frontend.search.search',['posts' => $posts,'tags' => $tags]);
       }
```

**EDIT 3**

there are two questions exsiting here.

ONE is that when i change to that ,it can output the result but all the result the database has. Not the keyword results.

Two is that when there are extra page, once i open the link http://localhost/html5lav/public/search?page=2, it just show an error:

**No query results for model [Post].**

Comment: Try removing $posts->toArray() on your controller

Comment: after my removing the entire $posts->toArray()  from Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts', $posts->toArray()) to Redirect::route('searchResults')->with('posts'), it shows ''Call to a member function links() on a non-object''

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to use $posts instead of $posts->toArray(). So, with('posts', $posts)

Comment: Also why in the world are you redirecting to another route only to render the view? Just return the view in the search method.

Comment: @NightMICU,with('posts', $posts) did not work. but with('posts') does kind of not showing any alert but cannot show any result, as i updated in the above edit,thanks

Comment: please try just returning the View in the `search()` method without redirecting to another route with data. So, return `View::make('frontend.search.search')->with('posts', $posts)->with('tags', $tags);`

Comment: See my answer's edits

Comment: @NightMICU see my edit 3,still not solved

Comment: did you try implementing my suggestions in my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

The initial issue most likely has to do with the unusual way you are displaying the search results; by passing the Eloquent collections via session to another method, only to display the View. You were also converting the `Post` Eloquent collection to a regular array with `->toArray()`, pagination requires a collection rather than an array.

The solution for that part:

```
public function search(){

        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

        if(empty($keyword)){
            return Redirect::route('/');
            //->with('message',array('type' => 'alert', 'content' => '不能为空'))
        }

        $posts = Post::where('content', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        $tags = Tag::where('count','>','0')->orderBy('count','desc')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();

        return View::make('frontend.search.search')->with('posts', $posts)->with('tags', $tags);
   }
```

After taking care of the initial issue, you reported that the pagination links are not working as expected - you click on Page 2 and do not have any `Post` results. If the route for the page where the user inputs a search term is also `/search`, there is a conflict. Instead, change the route that the search form posts to, perhaps `/searchResults` (which then loads the results using the `search` method). You may also want to consider using a `GET` rather than `POST` request, allowing users to bookmark their search results or share a link.

Regarding the issue of displaying all of the entries from the `posts` table, you need to review MySQL raw queries in Laravel. Swing by the documentation and look them up.

Comment: I just updated the changed and the unexpectiong error above,thanks

Comment: sorry,a bit busy yesterday. and the route for the page where the user inputs a search term is with the home page. so it should not have conflict as you said above. and i put the code in live site which search is all right except when too many results, it cannot work as i click the next page link.

Comment: Please try my suggestions. Use GET instead of POST, review raw SQL queries in Laravel's docs

Comment: I just use get in the form method and when i click the next page link,it shows: Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
 if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
 {
  throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
 }
});